# What is the carbon footprint of Spacex's plan for earth-to-earth transport plan compared to commercial aviation?

Tags: co2, environmental-protection, transportation

According to many articles around the web as well as the SpaceX official website (https://www.spacex.com/human-spaceflight/earth/index.html), Elon Musk plans to replace intercontinental flights with rockets traveling in a low Earth trajectory to send people to anywhere in the world in 30 minutes or less.  What I want to know is: Would sending people between continents on rockets produce more, the same, or less carbon emissions per person than intercontinental flights, assuming as little fuel as possible per person is burned when sending
the people into their low Earth trajectory?

Comment: it might be better to ask this question over at https://space.stackexchange.com/ using methane and oxygen as fuel can be made very effective so it can release less carbon than the burning of kerosene in jet engines will do.point to point transport with rockets on our planet is not realistic at this time and it might never be a realistic option for moving people or cargo.

Comment: @trondhansen you are right, there are several Q&A related to the burden on the atmosphere from future extensive use of kerosene/LOX.